# Get filename only

Tags: php, mysql

I have table :

```
==============
|id| document|
==============
|1 | doc1.txt|
|2 | doc2.txt|
==============
```

I wanna get the `document` without the extension. here's my code :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT document FROM tb ") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    $filename    = $row['document'];
    $title   = basename($filename);
}
```

But the rsult of `$title` still contain the extension. what's wrong? thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$title   = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

[`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) is more suitable in this case

Comment: That's a string and not a filename! :)

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: uhm, pardon? What is `filename`?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: no one told about file. It's a string that represents a filename

Comment: @PraveenKumar pathinfo takes a string as the argument, just like OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

#### You are manipulating a string, not a filename!

In your code, replace:

```
$title = basename($filename);
```

With:

```
$title = substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, "."));
```

I didn't use `pathinfo()` because, you are manipulating a string, and not a filename.

Comment: "You are manipulating a string, not a filename!" -- this phrase makes no sense

Comment: Well... Not sure if it works on a plain string. That's why. :)

Comment: you probably need to refresh your types knowledge: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php